# I am not able to understand the exact meaning of this code

Tags: c#

What do these lines of code mean?

```
foreach (DataRow row in distinctFlatDataTable.Rows)
{
    row["Diff_Min"] = (Convert.ToDecimal(row["Mins"] == DBNull.Value ? 0.0 : row["Mins"]) - Convert.ToDecimal(row["MIN"] == DBNull.Value ? 0.0 : row["MIN"]));
    row["Diff_Amt"] = (Convert.ToDecimal(row["Amount"] == DBNull.Value ? 0.0 : row["Amount"]) - Convert.ToDecimal(row["AMT"] == DBNull.Value ? 0.0 : row["AMT"]));
    row["Diff_Pft"] = (Convert.ToDecimal(row["Profit"] == DBNull.Value ? 0.0 : row["Profit"]) - Convert.ToDecimal(row["PFT"] == DBNull.Value ? 0.0 : row["PFT"]));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a collection of DataRows a Datarow `row` is selected in each instance of for each. The `row["Mins"]` representing `Mins` column in that row which is get converted into `Decimal`. Then compared with `DbNull.Value` for null check. If the value is `null` then 0.0 is taken else the original value from expression `Convert.ToDecimal(row["Mins"])`. 
Same logic is performing for `Convert.ToDecimal(row["MIN"]` & the result of both is get subtracted & stored into row["Diff_Min"].

Same logic for the statement 2 & 3.

Hope this will clear your doubt.

Comment: ...thanks brother...ur answer is what exactly i was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

For every row in a DataTable it calculates the difference between two fields, converts the result to a decimal value and stores it in another field in the same row. 
In line 1 the Min field is subtracted from the contents of field Mins, and the result stored in field Diff_Min.

Each line of code does the same thing, but with different source and target fields.

The ? and : part:

```
row["Mins"] == DBNull.Value ? 0.0 : row["Mins"]
```

is testing whether the source fields contain null values (DBNull.Value), and substitutes 0.0 in those cases. This is so that the calculation doesn't fail when one of the source fields happens to have a null value.

Comment: ...thank a lot....i am clear now